# Spring MVC RequestMapping regex with exclamation mark not matched?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a need to match a URI paths such as `/1.123!ref1` (including `/1.123` and `/1.123!ref1!ref2`) in a Spring MVC Controller, but I can't seem to figure out a regex that will match the ! (exclamation mark).

I have tried the following annotations on the controller method, without any luck:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

/1.123 -> id="1"
/1.123!ref1 -> id="1"
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:[^/]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

/1.123 -> 404 Not Found
/1.123!ref1 -> 404 Not Found
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:[\\d\\.!]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

/1.123 -> id=1.123
/1.123!ref1 -> 404 Not Found
```

Any ideas?
Is it even possible with Spring MVC?

Uses Spring Web 4.0.9 (also tried 4.2.2) with Jetty 9.3.6

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question...

Seems that this works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```